# Conceptual question about coordinate systems?

Tags: geometry

Spherical coordinates are non-Cartesian coordinate system. But when one talks about spherical coordinates per se, without any mention to specific geometry , are we talking about euclidean or non-euclidean type of coordinates ? Maybe i am mixing the concept of measurement vs the representation of points in a particular geometry.